# Regarding accurate Time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please help me understand this code.
I'm using *OracleSQLDeveloper 17.3*.

The command

```
sysdate - interval '15' minute
```

won't always give me accurate results.
It returns results like

```
15.000000000000000005 , 15.999999999999, 17.0000000000006.
```

Please help me understand what's going on...

Comment: To keep it short: Your cpu works in cycles which executes one after another and therefore is not really "real-time". Such inaccuracy is expected. If you want more accuracy you should use some kind of microcontroller or hardware that is designed for this high accuracy.

Comment: Can you please explain clearly. Sorry , i am not that technical , i did not understand clearly

Comment: A non-technical option you may apply is named `round`.

Comment: `sysdate - interval '15' minute` will never return `15.000` or `15.9999` - that expression returns a **date** value that's 15 minutes before "now", e.g. `2018-12-06 09:26:47.0` but definitely not `15.0000`

Answer (score 0):

This is an inaccuracy that you have to deal with [sysdate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SYSDATE.html#GUID-807F8FC5-D72D-4F4D-B66D-B0FE1A8FA7D2). There are numerous factors that can produce this inaccuracy. It depends on hardware and software/OS. Although [this paper](http://vision.psych.umn.edu/users/boyaci/Guide_v00/guidePrcsTime.pdf) is written for animations and gaming it may help you as it describes several sources of this problem a bit more technical.

The max accuracy of what Java - SQLDeveloper can handle this way is nanoseconds. e.g. 1m = 6x10^10ns.